# scheduling periodical threads with priority

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler, thread-priority

I have to implement a kind of multithreading application in java 8.

My application should run some Threads periodically, let's say once every 30 minutes. Each Thread should call an api, get the data from it and save into the database. The database is organized in this way:

```
Table A
Table B
Table C
Table D
Table E
Table F
Table G
Table H
```

`Tables F`, `G` and `H` have foreign keys to `Tables A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`.

This lead to have a `Thread` for each table to update:

```
Thread A -> Table A
Thread B -> Table B
Thread C -> Table C
Thread D -> Table D
Thread E -> Table E
Thread F -> Table F
Thread G -> Table G
Thread H -> Table H
```

Since some tables have foreign keys to other tables, the Threads should not start all at the same time, but first should start `Thread A`, `B`, `C` and `E` and once they have finished, then should start `Thread F`, `G` and `H`.

I have searched a lot on the internet for a possible solution, but I haven't found the right one for my situation.

For the moment I have implemented my code with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` that has the function `scheduleWithFixedDelay` that ensures me that the Threads are executed once every 30 minutes. Even if I schedule every thread with different priority, they all start at the same time and I have exception while executing insert/update in the tables with foreign keys.

Here is a snapshot of my code that might help to understand.

The `Thread-like` classes look like this:

```
public class AllarmReasonService implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AllarmReasonDAO dao = new AllarmReasonDAO();
        PagedResultContainer<AllarmReason> allarmReasonContainer = AllarmReasonApi.getInstance().getAllarmReasons();
        for(Iterator<AllarmReason> iterator = allarmReasonContainer.getData().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            AllarmReason allarmReason = iterator.next();
            dao.insertOrUpdateAllarmReason(allarmReason);
        }
    }
}
```

The `threadExecutor`:

```
public void threadExecutor(){
    initializeThreadMap();
    Stream<Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = threadTimerMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue());
    scheduler = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadTimerMap.size());

    for(Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> entryIterator = sorted.iterator(); entryIterator.hasNext();){
        Entry<String, Integer> entry = entryIterator.next();
        Runnable service = threadMap.get(entry.getKey());
        Thread thread = new Thread(service);
        thread.setPriority(entry.getValue());
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(thread, 0, 30 * 60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}

private void initializeThreadMap(){
        threadMap.clear();
        threadMap.put("causaliAllarme", new AllarmReasonService());
        threadMap.put("causaliLavorazione", new ManufactureReasonService());
        threadMap.put("celle", new CellService());
        threadMap.put("dipendenti", new EmployeeService());
        threadMap.put("ordiniLavorazione", new ManufactureOrderService());
        threadMap.put("parzialiLavorazione", new ManufacturePartialService());
        threadMap.put("qualita", new QualityService());
        threadMap.put("qualitaRilevata", new QualityDetectionService());
    }
```

And, finally, the `threadTimerMap` has `key = name of the module/thread (i.e. causaliAllarme)` and `value = priority` where priority is higher for modules to update first.

With this setting, I am not able to run first the most important Threads even if I set a certain priority.

Consider that I am not a pro with Thread and multiThread.

Any help would be apreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply spoken: Java thread priorities are broken. They depend on whatever the OS does about them. They are simply *not* the correct solution to your requirements.

Comment: Do you have to have one thread per table? Could you map the number of threads more closely to your DB design? i.e. one thread populates parent table(s) and then populates child(ren) table(s)?

Comment: @TomMac not really.. because the tables have more than one reference. For example, `Table A` is reference by all `Table F`, `G` and `H`. With your solution, `Table A` will be updated 3 times.

Comment: How about: define a task that runs every 30 minutes. That task does: creates threads for the A-E tables, then waits for them all to finish. Then creates threads for the F-H tables.

Comment: @FrancescoSgaramella - Please note that I have edited the `run` method in my answer to fix a mistake. If you have taken a copy of the code, please take another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such situations I'll advice to use `CompletableFuture` features.

```
// Declare your pool. Declare ThreadFactory also, it will be very
// helpful with debug, I promise :) 
int corePoolSize = 10;
ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(corePoolSize,
      new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Your-thread-%d").setDaemon(true).build());

List<CompletableFuture<Void>> dependencies = new ArrayList<>();

// Submit the threads for the first stage
dependencies.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(new AllarmReasonService(), pool));
dependencies.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(new ManufactureReasonService(), pool));
// ...
// do the same with all your stage-1 threads

// wait while stage 1 completed
try {
    for (CompletableFuture<Void> f : dependencies) {
        f.get();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    // log or re-throw
    pool.shutdownNow();
}

// stage 2
CompletableFuture.runAsync(new AllarmReasonService(), pool);
CompletableFuture.runAsync(new ManufactureReasonService(), pool);
// other required ...
```

Also you can aggregate futures with `CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture<?>...)` method and wait for single future.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is an interesting solution what you are proposing. But how this can be done procedurally every 30 minutes? This is also a core requirement.

Comment: @FrancescoSgaramella You wrap this whole thing in a runnable and run it every 30 minutes.

Comment: @FrancescoSgaramella, as @RealSkeptic mentioned you can wrap it with enclosing future to run it as per your needs. Also if you have some non-trivial dependencies, you can use `CompletableFuture.runAfterBothAsync` methods which will give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

You could join the two functions together using a `CountDownLatch`.

This code just illustrates the idea - there may be tidier ways to achieve this.

```
class SignalledRunnable implements Runnable {
    final CountDownLatch wait;
    final CountDownLatch signal;
    final Runnable it;

    public SignalledRunnable(CountDownLatch waitFor, CountDownLatch signal, Runnable it) {
        this.wait = waitFor;
        this.signal = signal;
        this.it = it;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (wait != null) {
            try {
                // Wait for pre-condition.
                wait.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Please remember to do something here.
            }
        }
        // Do it.
        it.run();
        if (signal != null) {
            // Signal post-condition.
            signal.countDown();
        }

    }

class A implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Update table A
    }
}

class F implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Update table F.
    }
}

public void test() {
    // Make F wait for A.
    A a = new A();
    F f = new F();
    CountDownLatch afSequencer = new CountDownLatch(1);
    // The A must signal at completion.
    Runnable ar = new SignalledRunnable(null, afSequencer, a);
    // The F should wait for that signal.
    Runnable fr = new SignalledRunnable(afSequencer, null, f);
    // You can now add ar and fr to your task queue and f will block until a completes.

}
```

NB: As @RealSkeptic points out, remember that the `f` thread will **block** until `a` completes so be sure your thread pool is large enough to handle as many blocked threads as can happen in your system.

Comment: One thing, though: you have to ensure that the thread pool is big enough to accommodate all of the runnables or ensure that the queue the dependency threads first, otherwise there will be a deadlock.